# How do I utilize execute_script method using Selenium to print dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

So for the last two weeks I picked up programming again, and I thought it would be fun to learn web-scraping. The first project I wanted to try was to scrape Cryptocurrency prices from Binance. I first tried Beautifulsoup, however that library can't access Javascript so I find it quite limited. I then moved on to Selenium and found that you cant actually write Javascript using `execute_script`  driver method.

But here comes the Caviar. If you log onto Binance and head over to the BTC/USDT pair and select the 1 second chart, you will see that the price is constantly updating. I tried a few methods to scrape and print the 1 second, first I tried Beautifulsoup which didn't work, I then tried using their Api, which works great, but unfortunately the api is limit to only display the average price per 5 min, which isn't what I want. Working Api code below for those that are interested ↓

```
import requests
import time

url_btc = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=BTCUSDT'
url_eth = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=ETHUSDT'

while True:
    response_btc = requests.get(url_btc)
    response_eth = requests.get(url_eth)
    data_btc = response_btc.json()
    data_eth = response_eth.json()
    print("Current price for Bitcoin is: " + data_btc['price'] + "\n" + "And the current price for Etherium is: " + data_eth['price'])

    time.sleep(1)

    #While this utilizes the api, it only gets the avg price per 5min. That's why you don't see the price change very much.  The point is the scrape the live price.
```

Moving on, so from a lot of Googling and reading some documentation I found `execute_script()` which apparently can get the live 1 second price from Binance and print it to console since Binance uses Javascript to update that price. However I don't know how I can use the Javascript to retrieve that 1 second price. Below is some more information for convenience's sake. Thanks in advance :)

Link: https://www.binance.com/en/trade/BTC_USDT?_from=markets&theme=dark&type=spot

Link to documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html

Element I'm trying to scrape ↓

```
<div class="showPrice" style="color: rgb(14, 203, 129);">30,455.26</div>
```

- Tried Beautifulsoup
- Tried Api
- Tried using Selenium and figuring it out, but can't
- Tried reading documentation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this:

```
price = driver.execute_script("""
  return document.querySelector('.showPrice').innerText
""")
```